# Циклическая перезагрузка windows

Tags: windows-7

Извините за вопрос не по теме.
Компьютер доходит до загрузки ОС и перезагружается бесконечно. Грешил на Погнутые шпильки и термопасту, шпильки не согнуты и даже заменил БП. Уже сложил руки, буду благодарен если поделитесь советами.

Comment: Ну так может ОС сломана?

Comment: По F8 пробовали в Safe Mode хотя бы грузиться?

Comment: Залил новую винду такая же проблема, да пробовал.

Comment: Через пол часа средством восстановления удаётся загрузить винду, но через 40-56 мин комп автоматически перезагружается. Удалил драйвера поставил новые проблема не ушла

Comment: Аппаратный сбой в бытовых условиях (да и не в бытовых тоже) проще всего ищется последовательной заменой компонентов системы. Ставите другое ОЗУ и смотрите, не исчезла ли проблема. Если не исчезла, то ставите другой винчестер и смотрите, не исчезла ли проблема. Если не исчезла, то ставите другую материнку и смотрите, не исчезла ли проблема. И так далее.

Comment: В чистом досе ещё тесты какие погонять можно

Comment: голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что ремонтировать оборудование надо в мастерской, а не в интернете.